# Fedora 20 NAT Configuration with firewalld

Tags: networking, router, fedora, nat

I'm trying to set up a simple masquerading gateway that will bridge between an internal network on `ens33` (192.168.1.0/24) and a private network on `ens37` (10.0.1.0/24). It's a VMWare image with two separate network interfaces, both in "Bridged" mode to the network.

A second VM is configured on the 10.0.1.0/24 network with a unique IP and can connect to the gateway. It cannot connect through the gateway, it's not being handled correctly.

The [Fedora `firewalld` documentation](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD) is not exceptionally clear on how you're supposed to use the zones to construct a NAT router.

My interpretation, which isn't working, is that the external interface should be on zone "external" and internal one should be "trusted" if you want it wide open.

The configuration looks roughly this:

```
# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
external
  interfaces: ens33
trusted
  interfaces: ens37
```

I've enabled network forwarding with sysctl:

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

All I'm looking for is the masquerading rule to kick in and NAT the traffic on the 10.0.1.0/24 network.

Answer (score 3):

I had the `sysctl` part done also; the additional command that got NAT/masquerade working for me was:

```
firewall-cmd [ --permanent ] --zone=external --add-masquerade
```

I got that from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/654687) which also has an XML file that may or may not still be necessary.